# Is there any script in svn to determine the names and number of folders present within a directory?

Tags: svn

I have a list of directories under my svn project
The structure is as follows:

ProjectACME 
 --Branches 
          --Branch1.0 
          --Branch2.0 
          --Branch3.0 
 --Trunk

Is there any script by which I can determine the number of directories/folders under Branches?

**Eg. I need to know a script which can tell me there are 3 branches (Branch1.0, Branch2.0, Branch3.0) under Branches directory**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$ svn list file:///var/svn-repos/ProjectACME/branches | wc -l
```

Or https / svn+ssh, any protocol you are using to look at your repo.

Comment: Thank you Wrikken.

I am looking for a couple of more things for my study:

1. If I create a Branch 1.0.0 from trunk or I create a branch 1.0.5 from 1.0.0, then is there any script which can tell me from svn log file that this branch 1.0.0 has been created from trunk or branch 1.0.5 has been created from 1.0.0 ??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hm, I know you can do it with a local repo by `svnlook changed --copy-info -r<the number the dir was added> /var/svn-repos/projectACME/`, and you could the find that revision number with `svn log --stop-on-copy file:///var/svn-repos/projectACME/branches/Branch1.0`. However, I know of no way to do it remotely....